# How do I filter this MySQL query to only include items not rated by a specific user?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

Given this sample dataset:

```
item
----
item_id  item_name  item_added
1        Apple      <date_time>
2        Banana     <date_time>

user
----
user_id  user_name
1        Alice
2        Bob
3        Carol

rating
------
rating_id  item_id  user_id  rating_value
1          1        1        3
2          1        2        4
3          1        3        5
4          2        1        5
5          2        2        2
```

I have this query to figure out which items are missing only one rating:

```
SELECT item.*,
       COUNT(rating_value) AS rating_count
  FROM item
LEFT JOIN rating ON item.item_id = rating.item_id
 GROUP BY item_id
   HAVING rating_count = 2
 ORDER BY item_name
```

How can I modify this query to show items that are only missing Carol's rating? The rating_count row is not essential. The only essential columns are item_id and item_name.

Thank you.

Comment: How does the movie table relate to the item table?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. All references to "movie" should have been to "item".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output the items only missing Carol's rating (user_id = 3 that needs to be passed as a parameter):

```
SELECT item.*, COUNT(rating.rating_value) AS rating_count 
 FROM item INNER JOIN rating ON item.item_id = rating.item_id AND 
      (3 NOT IN (SELECT r.user_id FROM rating AS r 
          WHERE r.item_id = rating.item_id))
 GROUP BY item_id
 HAVING rating_count = 2   /* (2 = number of users - 1) */
 ORDER BY item_name;
```

You have to replace all `item` by `movie` but your query mixes item and movie and the table was item so I did the query with item and I only saw the movie in the query too late.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select ...
From item 
    Left Join rating 
        On rating.item_id = item.item_id
            And rating.user_id = 3
Where rating.rating_id Is Null
Order By item.item_name
```

If you still wanted rating data, here's another form:

```
Select ...
From item 
    Left Join rating 
        On rating.item_id = item.item_id
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From rating As R1
                    Where R1.item_id = item.item_id
                        And R1.user_id = 3
                    )
Order By item.item_name
```

Comment: Understand that the key to the first query above is that it uses a left outer join. Many coders struggle to remember join types.

Comment: 1st query is good but I think the 2nd query won't work to count ratings as the `Not Exists` will be true when Carol not rated the item (OK) but also when `R1.item_id <> item.item_id` so it will return additional rows that will be added to the count.

Comment: ...and both 1st and 2nd queries will list all the item not rated by Carol and the OP wants the item not rated ONLY by Carol

Comment: Thomas: Thanks for your reply. Even though it's not what I was looking for, it has taught me some new tricks.